# Banco Sqlite não funciona em Unity Games compilados para Android

Tags: android, sqlite, unity3d

Estou usando o [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) como banco de dados de um jogo feito em **Unity** que funciona perfeitamente no **Unity Editor**, porém quando realizo o build para **Android** o jogo simplesmente não acessa o banco (nada é informado ou lançado).

O que posso fazer para que o banco sqlite seja acessível através do Android assim como no Unity Editor?

> **Programas/Versões** usadas:
> - Unity 5.3.1f1
> -Sqlite Precompiled Binaries for Windows 64 (sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3100200.zip
>   (688.01 KiB))

**Folder Structure:**

```
-- Assets/Database/MyDataBase.db
-- Assets/Scripts/PerguntaScript.cs
-- Assets/Plugins/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
-- Assets/Plugins/sqlite3.def
-- Assets/Plugins/sqlite3.dll
-- Assets/Plugins/System.Data.dll
```

**PerguntaScript.cs (Script que acessa o banco de dados Sqlite)**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

public class PerguntaScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private string connectionString;

    void Start () {
        connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/Database/DoencasDB.db";
    }

    private void GetPergunta(){
        using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + sqliteTabelasPerguntas[sqliteIndexTabelaPergunta] + " WHERE doenca_id=@id LIMIT 1";
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", doencaId));
                dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                    while(reader.Read()){
                        pergunta = reader.GetString(1);
                        alternativasId[0] = reader.GetInt32(3);
                        alternativasId[1] = reader.GetInt32(4);
                        alternativasId[2] = reader.GetInt32(5);
                        alternativasId[3] = reader.GetInt32(6);
                        alternativaCorretaId = reader.GetInt32(7);
                    }
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> OBS: Testado em Android: 4.4 e 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer com que funcione fora do ambiente de edição (neste caso no ambiente mobile) tive de fazer as seguintes alterações:

**1)** verificar qual o ambiente estou (através dos comentários de compilação determino qual código irá para o compilado).

**2)** verifico se o arquivo já foi aberto e armazenado pelo aplicativo (descompactado do jar (verificar a documentação da unity)) se não é necessário abrir o banco de dados e armazena-lo no local adequado (expresso por: `Application.persistentDataPath`)

```
public void GenerateConnectionString(string DatabaseName)
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string dbPath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + DatabaseName;
    #else
        //check if file exists in Application.persistentDataPath
        string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + DatabaseName;

        if (!File.Exists(filepath) || new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath).Length == 0)
        {
            // if it doesn't ->
            // open StreamingAssets directory and load the db ->
            #if UNITY_ANDROID
                WWW loadDb = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + DatabaseName);  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android
                while (!loadDb.isDone) { }  // CAREFUL here, for safety reasons you shouldn't let this while loop unattended, place a timer and error check
                // then save to Application.persistentDataPath
                File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDb.bytes);
            #elif UNITY_IOS
                var loadDb = Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + DatabaseName;  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in iOS
                // then save to Application.persistentDataPath
                File.Copy(loadDb, filepath);
            #elif UNITY_WP8
                var loadDb = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + DatabaseName;  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in iOS
                // then save to Application.persistentDataPath
                File.Copy(loadDb, filepath);
            #elif UNITY_WINRT
                var loadDb = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + DatabaseName;  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in iOS
                // then save to Application.persistentDataPath
                File.Copy(loadDb, filepath);
            #endif
        }
        var dbPath = filepath;
    #endif
    connectionString = "URI=file:" + dbPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar as bibliotecas de conexão do SQLite a seu projeto, o arquivo acredito que não é disponibilizado atualmente no site oficial do SQLite (mas você encontra facilmente por ai), trata-se de um arquivo com a extensão `.so`.

Você deve adiciona-lo em **/Assets/Plugins/Android**

Diferente de muitas bibliotecas que usamos como as `.dll` o Android usa as `.so`.

Fonte: [Documentação Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html).

Aqui no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615679/issue-accessing-sqlite-database-from-unity3d-on-android-device) um problema idêntico ao seu.

Comment: Mesmo adicionado esta este arquivo `.so` não funcionou.